# Azure App Service error HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm facing issue "`HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure`" while deploying web api to azure app service. Actually I have 2 deployment slots Prod and Staging.

Earlier we deployed web api to prod slot and it is working fine.
Now we created staging slot and deployed same webapi to staging slot.

In staging slot we are getting issue.
When I check `eventlog.xml` in kudu, I found below errors.

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled
>   exception. Exception Info:
>   Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException:
>   Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
>   Resource:  https://vault.azure.net,  Exception Message: Tried the
>   following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
>   Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
>   Resource:  https://vault.azure.net,  Exception Message: Tried to get
>   token using Managed Service Identity. Unable to connect to the Managed
>   Service Identity (MSI) endpoint. Please check that you are running on
>   an Azure resource that has MSI setup. Parameters: Connection String:
>   [No connection string specified], Resource:  https://vault.azure.net, 
>   Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access
>   token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not
>   found at
>   "D:\local\LocalAppData.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"
>   Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
>   Resource:  https://vault.azure.net,  Exception Message: Tried to get
>   token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or
>   batch file.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsyncImpl(String
>   authority, String resource, String scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.PostAuthenticate(HttpResponseMessage
>   response)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync(String
>   vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, Dictionary`2 customHeaders,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretsAsync(IKeyVaultClient
>   operations, String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1
>   providers)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException&
>   hostingStartupErrors)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at
>   MDHvNextAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, you have a managed identity assigned to your production environment which is used to access Azure Key Vault in order to get some secret.

When creating a new deployment slot you need to create another managed identity and grant access to it on Key Vault.

In summary: The managed identity is not shared between deployment slots.